# Spring boot @Async not working when overridden method is being called from super class

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I want my method to execute asynchronously without blocking the main thread.
For that purpose I did the required changes in order to use Spring boot @Asycn annotations.

1. Added `@EnableAsync()` in the main application class with `@SpringBootApplication`.
2. Implemented custom `AsyncConfig`

   ```
   public class AsyncConfig extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {
   @Lazy   
   @Autowired  
   private AsyncExceptionHandler asyncExceptionHandler;

   @Override  
   public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {  
     ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();  
     taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);  
     taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);  
     taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(500);  
     taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-thread-event-app");  
     taskExecutor.initialize();  
     return super.getAsyncExecutor();  
   }

   @Override
   public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {  
     return asyncExceptionHandler;  
   }
   }
   ```
3. Added `@Async` over the intended method.

This was working fine when I was calling a normal method.

But it is not executing asynchronously in following scenario:

1. I have a parent class `A`

   ```
    class A {  
        public void methodA(){  
            methodB();
        }

        //This need to be implemented in the child step.  
        @Async
        public void methodB(){
        }
    }
   ```
2. child class `B`

   ```
    class B extends A{
      @Async
      public void methodB(){}
    }
   ```
3. Calling `methodA()` of parent class `A` from @Controller class.

   @Autowired
   private B obj;

   ```
        @PutMapping(path = "/test-async", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   ```

   public String reprocessPurchaseOrders() {

   ```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    obj.methodA();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("solanki performAsyncAction took " + (end - start) + " milliseconds ! and the current Thread is : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
   return "";
   ```

   }

If I called `obj.methodB()`, it is working fine but not with above statement.
Can anyone help me this is happening?
As per my current implementation, I need `methodA()` to run before `methodB()`.

Comment: getAsyncExecutor() method should have @Bean annotation on it. look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) for more details

Comment: Code you have pasted isn't ok. obj is not spring managed as per your code.

Comment: Multiple things are wrong here. 1, you are creating an instance outside of the scope of Spring, no proxies, no aop, no async, 2. it is an internal method call that will not pass through the proxy, again no async.

Comment: @M.Deinum Edited the code. As I mentioned \@Async is working fine when I "obj.methodB()" is used but not with "obj.methodA()". As I know we cannot call the \@Async method from the same class. But in my case I cant annotate methodA() with \@Async as in future I may introduced other child class which I need to run synchronously.

Comment: You "fixed" 1, option 2 still applies. This simply isn't going to work, unless you go full-blown AspectJ with either load or compile time weaving. Which is more powerful than proxy based AOP but also harder to setup right (in my experience). So I would strongly suggest to find another way, as your solution won't work.